# During Pull request, Github runs "Junit" checks on "feature branch code" and not on the "After merged like code"

Tags: git, github, devops, pull-request

I have setup "Junit/integration" tests to run on every github pull request.

Now consider below scenario

```
...---A---B---C  master
           \
            D---F   feature1 of dev1
```

Next, `dev1` raise pull request of merging `feature1` to `master` and github trigger's "Junit/integration" tests via github action.

Now, If we observe closely, GitHub has build and run the tests at `Commit F`.

**As a repo maintainer, I expected that GitHub should have build and run the tests on the code that will be the outcome of this pull request.**
Diagrammatically(ref below), I expected GitHub to create a `github_tmp` branch, merge `master` and `feature1` into `github_tmp` and run the tests against this branch.
So that i as a repo maintainer can be very sure that "if i merge this pull request, my `master` branch will have the good code".
But currently behaviour of GitHub only proves that code is good at `commit F` and does not help to tell that repo will remain good after merging.

```
...---A---B------C  master branch
           \      \  
            \      M github_tmp branch.  <------
             \    / 
              D--F   feature1 of dev1
```

**PS:** Some friends told that you should follow a practice of rebasing the `feature1` branch, but I excepted that above-mentioned behaviour should be the default behaviour.

**I know I might be missing something or not having the correct perspective. How can I achieve the behaviour mentioned above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour.

Actions/tests running on a PR are running on the code that the PR contains, not the code that would eventually be merged into the main branch.

One of the reason is that the code in the PR might not even be mergeable into the main branch.

**You are right that using a "rebase" approach can help you achieve your goal though**. By ensuring that PR are always rebased on top of the main branch you are guaranteed that the code of the PR is the same code as the one that will be in the main branch once merged.

I believe there is a setting in GitHub to force PR to be rebased on top of the main branch before they can be merged.

Comment: Github setting wont help in running the tests on the "code that will be the outcome this PR".. how can it be achived

Comment: You'll need to rebase, wait for the tests to run again, then merge. I'm not familiar with GitHub exact settings but it should be feasible. Gitlab offer such an option.